# Group by a field that exist inside a nested query

Tags: mysql

i want to thank you  for contributing to the answer  here is an SQL fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/610e7/1

-- This query will return all the attributes of an issue

`select * from dataissue where issue  = '25998'`  .

What I want to  do  is  :

```
sum(value) count(value)    

where field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)'

and value  = 'Fermée' 

and  field = 'point_d_effort'

and value = 'récit'

and group it by value where field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)'
```

for example this query return the group by but the sum explode because we use the field of the outer query :

sqlfiddle.com/#!9/610e7/4

Comment: I find this very confusing. `value` is a text field, so what do you mean by `sum(value)`? There will be zero rows for which `field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' AND field = 'point_d_effort'`

Comment: Hi     ...   value      where     field  = 'point_d_effort'    is a number   .  (actually the value has number where field = 'point_d_effort'   )                        if you use these sql query you will see :   "  select value from dataissue where field = 'point_d_effort'     "

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your database's design. I simply don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i want to   have a sum(value),count('value')  where field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)'
and value  = 'Fermée' 
and  field = 'point_d_effort'
and value = 'récit'
and group it by value where field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)'  is like self joining the table  . with those criteria and grouping it with a particular field  and that field is version(s)_corrigée(s) ( to see clearer try using each of those criteria in a separate query )   what i want to do is to have all those criteria in one query and group it with that particular field

Comment: for example this query return the group by but the sum explode because we use the field of the outer query :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/610e7/4      in this query there is the count i need the sum ... now how to do a group by with a field in the inner query

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want something like this:

```
select sum(case when field = 'point_d_effort' then value + 0 end), as v 
       sum(field = 'point_d_effort') as cnt
from dataissue
group by issue
having sum(field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' and value  = 'Fermée') > 0 and
       sum(field = 'Type de demande' and value = 'récit')  > 0;
```

You have an entity-attribute-value (EAV) data structure.  One method is to first aggregate by key.  If you want the total across all issues, then you need another aggregation:

```
select sum(v), sum(cnt)
from (select sum(case when field = 'point_d_effort' then value + 0 end), as v 
             sum(field = 'point_d_effort') as cnt
      from dataissue
      group by issue
      having sum(field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' and value  = 'Fermée') > 0 and
             sum(field = 'Type de demande' and value = 'récit')  > 0
    ) t
```

Comment: I'm glad someone understands the question. Isn't it bad practice to put multiple data types in one column?

Comment: here is the field and the value linked to them:                                          field                               value                                                 version_corrigee ----> (   sprint 1 , sprint 5 ...)                                                                 type de demande -----> recit                                                                                    etat         -------> fermee                                                                        point_d_effort --->numbers  ( 10,20)

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni . . . The column only has one datatype, probably a string.  Yes, encoding other values as strings is often discouraged, but EAV bottles are legitimate data models and have their uses.